# How to read a csv into a dict where the values are a list - then use this for different for different csv files

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am trying to read a csv file into a dictionary where for each row, the first column of the csv file will be a dictionary key and the remaining columns will be the values in a list (ignoring the header row).

I have got a solution that works but I have hardcoded the columns and what I want is something that works on any number of columns (because I have multiple csv files with different numbers of columns that I want to use it on).

My data in one of the csv files is:

```
name,test1,test2,test3
dave,66,74,62
rob,59,65,60
nic,71,68,73
```

This is the code that I have used

```
import sys
import csv

# Create a dict (where the values are a list) to store the data in memory
database = {}

# Open the csv file and read the contents into memory
filename = sys.argv[1]
with open(filename, "r") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    # Ignore the header
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        # Read the first column of the csv (name) as the key, then read the remaining columns as a list for the values
        database[row[0]] = [int(row[1]), int(row[2]), int(row[3])]
    print(database)
```

The output for the print(database) is

```
{'dave': [66, 74, 62], 'rob': [59, 65, 60], 'nic': [71, 68, 73]}
```

The problem I have is that when I need to read in another csv file with more columns, this code will only work for 4 columns (unless I extend it) for row[4], row[5] etc...

Is there a way I can rewrite the code to just read in row[1] all the way through to row[n] in the csv file? Where n is the number of the last column in the csv file.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Just started learning Python, I have been searching but I wasn't able to find anything to help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `database[row[0]] = [int(x) for x in row[1:]`. Same as saying `[int(row[1]), int(row[2]) ... int(row[n])]`

Comment: Yeah, that's so basic, bro

Comment: @OriDavid - that answer is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered `pandas`?

```py
filename = sys.argv[1]
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
dct = dict(zip(df['name'], df.drop('name', axis=1).apply(list, axis=1)))
```

With the data you show as example:

```py
>>> dct
{'dave': [66, 74, 62], 'rob': [59, 65, 60], 'nic': [71, 68, 73]}
```

If instead you want to use `csv` and loops, you can do it too (slower would be my guess):

```py
with open(filename) as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    # Ignore the header
    next(reader)
    database = {row[0]: [int(x) for x in row[1:]] for row in reader}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, the 2nd (slower) option is exactly what I was after. Just starting out so trying to keep it as simple as possible at the moment but I will look into pandas.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separete in the csv file key and value for ex:

Key - value 1,value2 etc and after that you can use split function split(“-“)

with open(“samepath.csv”) as f:
for line in f:
(key,val)= line.split(“-“)
dict[key]= int(val)

Answer (score 0):

Or just use list comprehension.

```
import sys
import csv

# Create a dict (where the values are a list) to store the data in memory
database = {}

# Open the csv file and read the contents into memory
filename = sys.argv[1]
with open(filename, "r") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    # Ignore the header
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        # Read the first column of the csv (name) as the key, then read the remaining columns as a list for the values
        database[row[0]] = [int(row[x]) for x in range (1, len (row))]
    print(database)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve that without using the `csv` module.

```py
import sys

database = {}
with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as file:
    next(file)
    for line in file:
        vals = line.strip().split(",")
        database[vals[0]] = [int(val) for val in vals[1:]]
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I was looking into line.strip but couldn't make it work. I will try this option too.